# How to calculate information content of a DNA sequence

Tags: dna, information

How does one calculate the information content of DNA sequence like ATCGGCT where mutation rate of G's is 10% and the most common mutation product binds with C and A with equal frequency.

I know that the individual information of a sequence is the dot product of the sequence and the weights matrix for each base. Essentially I = sum (base1xweight + base2xweight + ...)

What I can't figure out is how to determine the the weight of each base so as to incorporate the 10% probability of mutation of G's.. Can anyone help me figure that out

EDITED since wording may be confusing:
Original problem says:
" Spontaneous deamination of exocyclic amine is dG (deoxyguanosine) can occur occasionally in DNA strand. Given probability of this occurring  during the time it takes DNA polymerase to copy DNA is 20% per dG in a particular DNA. Given that most common deamination product pairs with dC and dA with equal frequency calculate information content during DNA replication in the given sequence. "
     As an example I choose ATCGGCT and changed it to 10% deamination of dG.

PROPOSED SOLUTION:
For sequence ATCGGCT,
I am only consider the initial strand bases A,T,C are 2 bits a base, given by I=-1/ln(2)ln(n_before/n_after) ,where n_before = 1, and n_after = 4
In the case of mutated G (Gm) , 
I say, I = -1/ln(2)ln(1/3)= 1.58 bits , n_after=3 since A,C are equivalent to Gm

Perfect copy would give us 7 bases x 2 bits each = 14 bits content of strand.
Since there are 2 G's, with 10% change of mutating --> 0.02 of G in strand will mutate.

Thus I content during replication,
    Information content I(ideal) - I(inc. mutation) = 14-0.03 = 13.97 bits during time of replication

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. Have you already tried to solve this yourself? If so then it would help if you show what you have tried and why you think it is incorrect (or correct).

Comment: "the mutation rate of G's is 10 %" what does this phrase mean? For example, are you saying that for every cell division a G residue has a 1/10 chance of mutating (and that the other bases have a 0/10 chance of mutating?)? In this model, what base does a G mutate into? One of the other 3 bases, randomly? "The most common mutation product binds with C and A" this phrase does not have a clear sense to me. Since there are only 3 choices, G could mutate into A or C or T, but none of those will bind with C and A with equal frequency, do you see what I mean?

Comment: Since DNA is double-stranded, if the sense strand is 5'-ATCGGCT-3' then the antisense strand (or reverse complement) will be 5'-AGCCGAT-3', so there are two G's on the top strand and two more G's on the bottom strand, did you take that into account?

Comment: This sounds like computing science/statistics rather than biology. Where does this mathematical formula you quote for information content come from? I've never heard of it and I can't see how it relates to anything 'real' in  genetic information.

Comment: I think I have a solution..
I am only considering 1 strand based on original problem wording, however mdperry I did consider the second strand. I am glad you also brought that up.
David the formulas come largely from (https://schneider.ncifcrf.gov/paper/ri/latex/ )

So my soluion

Comment: Thanks @Valentin-Angelo Uzunov. More mathematics than computer science even. I'll pass on this one.

Comment: So I think you have answered the question yourself. While I am no expert, I think Schneider presents the most thoughtful, and clearest descriptions and explanations in his many publications on this subject. I also appreciate your clarification of the question, and now understand the answers to the points I raised. 14 bits for a 7-mer sounds correct to me.  I don't really understand what a student is supposed to learn from doing this exercise, with the mutations etc. but I suspect you have the answer they are looking for.

Comment: I guess we will find out.
Actual sequence was AGCCGATTTGGGAAAAATCG, = 40bits without. 2bit / base. 
When 20% mutation of G is taken into account. 
If 20% of G will be mutated, then that = 1.2 bses ~ 1 based in the sequence will be likely mutated during replication
The information content of a mutated G = 1.58 bits. thus, deltaI for that bit is 2 - 1.58 = 0.42 bit lost from mutation 
Thus information content is 40 - 0.42 = 39.6 bits during replication. 
That is my final answer.